# How to put youtube captions in a list?

Tags: python, youtube-api

The "text" string contains the captions of the youtube video. How do I put these captions in separete lists per video.

```
videos = get_channel_videos(channel_id)
video_ids = []  # list of all video_id of channel
 
for video in videos:
    video_ids.append(video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
 
for video_id in video_ids:
    try:
        responses = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(
            video_id, languages=['en'])
        print('\n'+"Video: "+"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+str(video_id)+'\n'+'\n'+"Captions:")
        for response in responses:
            text = response['text']
            print(text)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a dictionary of lists, rather than just a lot of lists:

```py
videos = get_channel_videos(channel_id)
video_ids = []  # list of all video_id of channel
 
for video in videos:
    video_ids.append(video['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])

# make your dictionary here
captions = {}
 
for video_id in video_ids:
    if video_id not in captions:
        # initialize empty list for each id
        captions[video_id] = [] 

    try:
        responses = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(
            video_id, languages=['en'])
        print('\n'+"Video: "+"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+str(video_id)+'\n'+'\n'+"Captions:")
        for response in responses:
            text = response['text']

            # append to that list here
            captions[video_id].append(text)

            print(text)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

### For multiple fields

You'll want a dictionary of dictionaries for this:

```py
for video_id in video_ids:
    if video_id not in captions:
        # initialize empty list for each id
        captions[video_id] = {'Transcript': [], 'Title': None}
    
    try:
        responses = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(
            video_id, languages=['en'])
        print('\n'+"Video: "+"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+str(video_id)+'\n'+'\n'+"Captions:")
        for response in responses:
            text = response['text']

            # append to that list here
            captions[video_id]['Transcript'].append(text)

            print(text)

        captions[video_id]['title'] = response['title']
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Comment: Do you know how I can add the title of the youtube video to the dictionary? so example out put is {'Key': ['transcript'],[ 'title']}

Comment: @SlimDowning see newest edit

Comment: The value 'None' Is in the title dictionary in each of the rows whn the code is executed. Also in the snippet 'captions[video_id]['title'] = response['title']' Pycharm gives an error that the Name 'response' can be undefined

Comment: True, if `responses` is empty, then `response` wouldn't be defined

Comment: I would like the response to be filled with the title currently it is appearing as 'none'